# does openGauss MOT support cross-engine query now?

Tags: open-gauss

As in the documentation, it says `No cross-engine (Disk+MOT) queries, views or transactions. Planned for 2021.` How can we enable the cross-engine query?

Answer (score 0):

Cross-engine transactions and queries (+MVCC) are expected before Q4 2022, as part of a major release of openGauss with many additional features both in MOT (the Memory Optimized Tables storage engine) and in the openGauss in general.
thanks;